# Compare Arrays and Remove Duplicates from the Final Array. Pokedex App

Tags: javascript, node.js, pokeapi

I create a Pokédex app, but i ran in some Problems with the double type Pokémon:

I call pokeapi twice to 2 endpoints (one for each Type), and i need to compare the Results in different Ways.

```js
let a = {
        "double_damage_from": [
            {
                "name": "ground",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/5/"
            },
            {
                "name": "rock",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/6/"
            },
            {
                "name": "water",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/11/"
            }
        ],
        "half_damage_from": [
            {
                "name": "bug",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/7/"
            },
            {
                "name": "steel",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/9/"
            },
            {
                "name": "fire",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/10/"
            },
            {
                "name": "grass",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/12/"
            },
            {
                "name": "ice",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/15/"
            },
            {
                "name": "fairy",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/18/"
            }
        ],
        "no_damage_from": []
    };


let b = {
        "double_damage_from": [
            {
                "name": "fighting",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/2/"
            },
            {
                "name": "ground",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/5/"
            },
            {
                "name": "steel",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/9/"
            },
            {
                "name": "water",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/11/"
            },
            {
                "name": "grass",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/12/"
            }
        ],
        "half_damage_from": [
            {
                "name": "normal",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/1/"
            },
            {
                "name": "flying",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/3/"
            },
            {
                "name": "poison",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/4/"
            },
            {
                "name": "fire",
                "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/10/"
            }
        ],
        "no_damage_from": []
    };
```

I need to Compare the Data and get the Matches in a array.
This works fine and i got the 4x, 1x, and 1/4x damage in a array:

```js
getMatch(a, b) {
        let matches = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (let e = 0; e < b.length; e++) {
                if (a[i].name === b[e].name) matches.push(a[i]);
            }
        }
        return matches;
    }

compareTypes(a, b) {
        let four_damage_from = this.getMatch(a.double_damage_from, b.double_damage_from);
        let double_damage_from = [];
        let normal_damage_from = this.getMatch(a.double_damage_from, b.half_damage_from);
        let half_damage_from = [];
        let quarter_damage_from = this.getMatch(a.half_damage_from, b.half_damage_from);
        let no_damage_from = this.getMatch(a.no_damage_from, b.no_damage_from);

        let matches = { four_damage_from, double_damage_from, normal_damage_from, half_damage_from, quarter_damage_from, no_damage_from };
        return matches;
    }
```

to find the correct types for double_damage_from i have to merge a.double_damage_from and b.double_damage_from e.g. to c.double_damage_from. then i have to remove from c.double_damage_from all types that are in four_damage_from, normal_damage_from, quarter_damage_from, no_damage_from to get the correct 2x types, the same with half_damage_from.

I tried many solution but i didn't figure out how to solve this.

greetings Raphi

Answer (score 0):

It Works with lodash, i need to think a bit about but basically works.

```js
removeMatch(union, remove, double = false) {
        union = _.differenceBy(union, remove.four_damage_from, 'name');
        union = _.differenceBy(union, remove.normal_damage_from, 'name');
        union = _.differenceBy(union, remove.quarter_damage_from, 'name');
        // union = _.differenceBy(union, remove.no_damage_from, 'name');
        if(double) {
            union = _.differenceBy(union, remove.half_damage_from, 'name');
        } else {
            union = _.differenceBy(union, remove.double_damage_from, 'name');
        }
        return union;
    }
```